# Issue regarding Graphics 2D drawString

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have written my own Pie chart class and have decided to add a displayValues() which basically displays values, one of the parameters is Direction which is my ENUM consisting of LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM.

Basically the drawString will draw according to the Direction. The other parameter is also the padding between the String and the Pie Chart.

Everything is going well however the issue comes up when I want to create a padding when direction == LEFT.

Issue being that I cannot set the drawString(String str, getX() - 10, int y) as the string will still go inside the chart.

I would like to be able to keep the padding from right to left as opposed to the usual left to right. Is this possible?

Here's what I'm trying to get at:
[image]

Comment: It'd be useful if you included some relevant code in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you're looking to use the [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontFormatException.html) class to help you determine the size of your Strings that you are placing on your GUI. If you know the width of your String, the padding, and the left border of the bounding rectangle of your arc, you should be able to correctly place your label text.

Comment: I will in a moment, need to finish writing a small part. I shall try to give a graphical representation in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `g` is your `Graphics` object, use

```
int textWidth = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(str)
```

to get the width of the text you want to draw. Then you can replace the `getX() - 10` with `getX() - textWidth - 10`, which will position the text so that the end of it is 10 pixels to the left of getX(), as desired.